# Zend Framework 2 invalidate translator cache

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization, zend-framework2

I have this code:

```
'translator'  => array(
...
'cache' => array(
    'adapter' => array(
        'name'    => 'Filesystem',
        'options' => array(
            'cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../../data/cache',
            'ttl'       => '3600'
        )
    ),
    'plugins' => array(
        array(
            'name'    => 'serializer',
            'options' => array()
        ),
        'exception_handler' => array(
            'throw_exceptions' => true
        )
    )
)
```

The question is, how do I invalidate it not by TTL?

For example, I KNOW when the translation was changed so I want to invalidate in on demand but I have not found a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The translator component does not utilize the `TaggableInterface` so you have to know the cacheId which the translator generates to clear the item from you storage adapter. You can use the following code to simply generate the same id and remove the item. Call this from your service or some event listener.

```
$translator = $sm->get('McvTranslator');
$textDomain = 'default';
$locale = 'en';

$cacheId = 'Zend_I18n_Translator_Messages_' . md5($textDomain . $locale);
$translator->getCache()->removeItem($cacheId);
```

Comment: The problem with this that I have many languages... And to invalidate them all, will mean to iterate over all of them...

Comment: I wouldn't be so bothered by this approach. If you already have a list of supported locales for you application available you can easily iterate them and invalidate. Alternatively you can overwrite the translator component and implement a tag for each textDomain and call clearByTag when you want to invalidate, but behind the scenes ZF will still unlink the same amount of files on your filesystem, so you'll not have any performance benifits of using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set Ttl = 0 (always), and when the cache (file) is not valid anymore -- delete it.

Comment: But at THAT very moment the Cache already loaded... How can I set TTL 0, I need to invalidate it and to reload the new one.

Comment: In the config file where you have 3600.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it: 
Find a point in your code where you call `addTranslation`.

For example:

```
$translate = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');
$translate->addTranslation(array(
            'content' => "$dir/$locale.mo",
            'locale' => $locale
        ));
```

Change the `addTranslation` function to add `reload => true` , like this:

```
$translate->addTranslation(array(
            'content' => "$dir/$locale.mo",
            'locale' => $locale,
        'reload' => true
        ));
```

Refresh your page.
Voila.
Remeber to remove `reload` after that, otherwise you will have no cache.